# Ubuntu won't dual-boot; Tried BootRepair and still nothing

Tags: dual-boot

Title pretty much says it all. I've recently installed Ubuntu 18 on my laptop. Installation went well; I left it some free space after resizing my windows partitions and selected the "Install alongside Windows" option.

The problem is that it boots me right into Windows. I tried using BootRepair three times now, and followed their advice of working in cmd, but it didn't fix my issue. Secure boot is off, and so is the Windows quickboot option.

Another thing: I tried to install Ubuntu for dual-booting a long time ago, but I did something wrong at the time and got an error message that sounded like "Missing Bootable [something]" along with an icon of a HDD above it. To fix it I had to create a thing in the bios that accessed one of the Windows boot files(I think. I can't remember the name of the error and therefore any guides to give an example of what I did)

Answer (score 1):

### Tell your BIOS where to go

When you power on your machine press the key(s) to invoke the BIOS setup screen.

Then locate the screen containing the boot up order.

Find the "Ubuntu" boot option and move it higher up the list above the "Windows" boot option.

Save your BIOS changes and exit BIOS setup.

Now `grub` will appear to let you select between Windows and Ubuntu in a normal dual boot setup.

Previously the BIOS was booting directly into Windows and `grub` was never being loaded to give you a choice.

Comment: I would, but Ubuntu doesn't show up anywhere